# accessing directive variable from parent's parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-ui, angularjs-scope

I have a case using kendo editor.

**First controller**

```
app.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.Html = "<div> Hello World</div>";
}
```

**2nd Controller For Tempalte**

```
app.controller('SecondController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.Options= [{Options1, Option2}];
}
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('htmlEditor', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            documentName: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {               

            $http.get("ngview/TemplateEditor.html")
            .success(function (data) {
                element.html($compile(data)(scope));                    
            });              
        }
    }

}]);
```

**TemplateEditor.html** (I am using SecondController Here in Template)

```
<div ng-controller="SecondController">
<textarea kendo-editor k-ng-model="documentName" k-encoded="false" k-     
options="{{Options}}"></textarea>
 </div>
```

**Page HTML** (Where I am using FirstController)

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController" class="col-md-8">
    <div html-editor="HtmlEditor"
         document-name="Html">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, If make some changes to html, and change text from hello world to "Hello Every Body" I am getting same one value which is assigned to which is,

```
  $scope.Html = "<div> Hello World</div>";
```

JSFiddle example is
https://jsfiddle.net/aqdasiftekhar/HB7LU/19160/

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code that the `$scope.Html` variable is being referenced anywhere other than the first controller, so I can't see how the `kendo-editor` would even know the value in the first place, let alone be able to update it.

Comment: my mistake,
document-html="DocumentHtml" is actaully
document-html="Html"

Comment: but your directive scope is expecting a `document-name` attribute, not `document-html`

Comment: fixed again, thanks for highlighting, actually i typed mistakenly, now i corrected. the issue is still there

Comment: why you just not use `templateUrl` ?

Comment: because i am receiving file in other controller where i am passing its html to directive only

Comment: Yeah, use `templateUrl`, and your second controller is unnecessary, it is probably causing the conflict, just create the `Options` array in the directive `link` function scope

Comment: it is not conflict so far i am able to access thing with 
$scope.$$nextSibling.$$childHead.documentName

Comment: whereas, i want to access it using its scope. because it is not returning complete html except changing i made

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqdasiftekhar/HB7LU/19160/

Comment: @Aqdas, it interesting: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YfwgiWFs7Zmi1uLq2pbL?p=preview) if you remove isolated scope, all work without parent, just direct property. Also, as you can see in plunkr, textarea with `ng-model` work ok and with isolated scope, but `k-ng-model` not

Comment: yeah, but my requirement is isolated scope. anyway, i am done with my issue. thank you very much for your support. my solution is below

Comment: you not need in isolated scope, because you not use it, and instead get property directly you use ugly approach `$parent.$parent.$parent....` that do almost same

Comment: so any suggestion to access and implement?

Comment: @Aqdas, you can see sample in plunkr above

Answer (score 0):

A working example of your code on plunkr would be useful here, but at first glance it appears the problem is:

```
k-ng-model="documentName"
```

You probably meant:

```
k-ng-model="{{documentName}}"
```

which would cause documentName to be resolved to Html, and therefore bind the textarea to $scope.Html.

Comment: @Aqdas, so can you provide sample working plunker with your code?

Comment: @Aqdas, the example you've shown does not have 2 controllers, it only has 1.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/X9mIC3AOR33IV4gTlwgl

I have created plunker but i dnt know what is missing because i use jsfiddle

Comment: @Aqdas, you can provide jsfiddle, if it work for you

Comment: here it is working but i still have one angualr issue. if you can help out to fix

Comment: i used references same as http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/angular
sample running is - with one angular issue
 http://plnkr.co/edit/X9mIC3AOR33IV4gTlwgl

Answer (score 0):

So after struggling long,

I fixed by changing by referring parent's (SecondController) parent's (Directive's Scope) parent (FirstController) object to k-ng-model in template file

In  **TemplateEditor.html** Change Following Code

```
<div ng-controller="SecondController">
 <textarea kendo-editor k-ng-model="documentName" k-encoded="false" k-     
 options="{{Options}}"></textarea>
</div>
```

**To**

```
<div ng-controller="SecondController">
   <textarea kendo-editor k-ng-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.Html" k-  
   encoded="false" k-options="{{Options}}"></textarea>
</div>
```

After above change, **I have no need of variable** defined in Directive

```
scope: {
        documentName: "="
},
```

Thanks to all of you guys who tried to help me :-)